# Is it possible to install apache derby eclipse plugin in myeclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse, derby

Ive got myeclipse ide, and want to install the ui plugin for derby so I can access ij from inside eclipse. The problem is when I drop the ui plugin components into the plugins folder the plugins dont seem to load. Is there anything whacky I need to do to tell myeclipse to load these plugins?

I am following http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_howto.html
Myeclipse has 10.5.1.1 of the core plugin already intalled and I am dropping the 1.1.2 versions of the ui plugins in to the plugins folder.

Comment: What's the error you get? What does your Eclipse log say?

Comment: I get no error. Theres nothing relating to these plugins in the error log.

Comment: For modern Eclipse and Derby, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645223/is-it-possible-to-use-derby-from-apache-in-eclipse-now-that-they-stopped-develop?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok bit of reading revealed in myeclipse you have to put your plugins under a folder called dropins.

As per http://www.genuitec.com/blog/?p=1628#dropins