# Is it possible to use derby from apache in Eclipse now that they stopped developing the derby plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, database, derby

I would like to use Derby from apache in order to include database management on a desktop application that I'm currently developing.

Unfortunately I figured out that they have stopped developing this plugin and all the tutorials I've read online refer to this plugin.

So my question is, how can I use the latest version of Derby on eclipse? What steps should I follow? I would like my application to be standalone and easily transferable.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Derby is just like other databases that provide interface through JDBC. You don't need a specific plugin to connect with Derby. Just use the usual JDBC routines.

Basic steps:

1. If you want to use the latest Derby version, first you need to download it from [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html)
2. You need to include the jar in your classpath.
3. You just need to make connections and perform queries using JDBC, as better explained at the [Oracle JDBC Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html).

Answer (score 1):

Ditto pram.

I'm using Derby in a Java app I'm developing with Eclipse, and I didn't know there was a plug-in. I connect to Derby like I would to any other database. I use the Derby command-line interface to manage the tables. \

(One feature of other db's I would have liked to see in Derby: having SQL extensions to display db metadata, like MySql's "show" and "describe" commands. Derby has these in the command-line interface, but they're apparently implemented there rather than in the SQL engine itself, so you can't use them outside of the CLI. Bummer. When I'm developing, I often build an ad hoc query screen into the app that lets me type in and execute arbitrary queries. (And no, I don't deploy this to public websites.) But I digress.)

I don't know what the plug-in does for you. I've never used an Eclipse plug-in for any database.

Answer (score 0):

The plug-in is still available in source form, and instructions for building it are available on the Derby website: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/db/derby/code/trunk/plugins/eclipse/Readme.txt?view=markup

From time to time the instructions for building the plug-in change; you might wish to check into the status of this issue for further updates: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-5272