# Eclipse and derby

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

I've installed derby according to [this guide](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_download) and created database in it's ij console. How can I use this database from eclipse?
I've downloaded db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin there isn't any jars there.

Comment: Sure it has: db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin.zip\db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin\lib\

Comment: Perhaps this related question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645223/is-it-possible-to-use-derby-from-apache-in-eclipse-now-that-they-stopped-develop?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

After the installation of derby .
Fire up eclipse.
Create a java project. Write down any jdbc example program.

Assuming that you want to run a client - server based connection and you have setup class path correctly if not follow this [link](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/getstart/tgssetupjavaenvir.html).
Start the derby network server using the command

```
java -jar %DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbyrun.jar server start
```

In the eclipse project file right click on it and go to properties->Java Build Path->Libraries
Click on Add External JARs. Now browse to the derby installation directory and lib folder and select the following jar files
1. derby.jar 2. derbyclient.jar 3. derbynet.jar 4. derbytools.jar 5. derbyrun.jar

Thats it now your java program will be able to access the derby database that you create.

For step by set procedure you can refer to this [link.](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html)