# Add Derby Nature in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, derby

I have installed the new version of eclispe and derby. I have also the three directories (ui, core and plugin doc).
Still to get derby server started, I only mange to do it from outside eclipse. I cannot manage to start the server from within eclipse or add derby nature to a project.
Can anyone helpout?

Comment: The Derby plugins are very out of date, they may well not work on the current Eclipse.

Comment: Try this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645223/is-it-possible-to-use-derby-from-apache-in-eclipse-now-that-they-stopped-develop?rq=1