# Is the Apache Derby plugin for Eclipse not further developed?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, derby

I thought about installing the Apache Derby plugin to my eclipse.

On https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/derby_plugin.html I found:

> Download the Derby core plug-in zip from the Apache Derby site: http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html. The plug-in is available for download from each Derby release download page.

The current release is **Apache Derby 10.11.1.1** but the plugin is only available on the download-page of the release **Apache Derby 10.8.2.2**.

Did the development of the eclipse-plugin stop and/or is there an alternative?

Comment: Try this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645223/is-it-possible-to-use-derby-from-apache-in-eclipse-now-that-they-stopped-develop?rq=1