# how to install apache derby eclipse(mars) plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, derby, eclipse-mars

I cannot get the plugin from the Apache derby site. it looks like it is missing. in the website. Also i installed Eclipse (mars) via oomph installer and i cannot see the folder named plugins.
I cannot find the plugin link in the latest version 10.12.1.1 
I how ever got an older version 10.8.2.2 and put the plugin in dropins folder of eclipse and nothing happens.

it is confusing where to start. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Derby stopped doing an Eclipse plugin quite a long time ago. The old plugin you found is probably an old style plugin which Mars no longer supports by default.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645223/is-it-possible-to-use-derby-from-apache-in-eclipse-now-that-they-stopped-develop?rq=1