# Using Apache Derby from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

I have the following problem:

1. I have installed Eclipse
2. I unzipped the two Derby Eclipse plugins - derby_core_plugin_10.2.2.zip and derby_ui_plugin_1.1.0.zip  into mine eclipse installation folder (ECLIPSE_ROOT).
3. I have copy the file derbyclient.jar from that folder to mine TOMCAT_ROOT/lib folder
4. When I start the Eclipse ->Choose Window > Preferences. Navigated to Connectivity > Driver Definitions. I have selected the Derby 10.2 folder and click Add.In the New Driver Definition dialog, I selected Derby Client JDBC Driver and have click OK.I have navigated to the location of the derbyclient.jar file on mine system and click OK

When I create a new JavaProject and with right-click on it try to find  Apache Derby > Add Apache Derby Nature - it does not appear.

I have tried everything but it still not working.

Please if someone have any idea what the reason can be, let me know :)

Comment: Those plugins are very old and use a plugin format that Eclipse no longer supports by default. Derby no longer ships Eclipse plugins.

Comment: What do you plan to do with stuff from 2005 ? It is for Eclipse 3.1 ! https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/derby_plugin.html

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Simply adding a derby jar to your build path or what?

Comment: My goal is to do the following: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps%2Findex.html

I need to create a simple application for one of my university courses, but I am not very advanced in Java and I donr have sufficient time, cause I need to present this project on Monday morning, which is less than 48h from now.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12645464/193453