# How to Install Apache Derby in Eclipse 4.5.1?

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

How to Install Apache Derby in Eclipse 4.5.1?
I tried to do it in many ways but failed.
Can anyone explain?

Comment: Can you add more details? How did it fail?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645223/is-it-possible-to-use-derby-from-apache-in-eclipse-now-that-they-stopped-develop/12645464#12645464

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to include derby.jar in your project classpath. Jar file can be found in under JDK/db/lib directory for Java 7+ versions.