# Incorporating Derby into eclipse projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

I have "db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin" installed on my computer and my `$DERBY_HOME` variable is pointing to the bin directory.

I can run client-server examples on the command line, but how do I go from here to implementing an embedded database into my eclipse projects?  Is there an eclipse plugin I can't find on their website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645223/is-it-possible-to-use-derby-from-apache-in-eclipse-now-that-they-stopped-develop?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a Derby Eclipse plug-in but it was discontinued a long time ago.

Just put the Derby jars in one of your plug-ins (or create a separate plug-in containing the jars).