# Eclipse Mars How to add plugin DERBY database

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

I know how to use DERBY using CMD, I followed the tutorials in [Apache website](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/index.html). Now I will use DERBY in eclipse which requires the **core** and the **ui** zip files. I watched a tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F43nOvKQiNU) but when I open my **eclipse directory** there is no **plugin** folder but still I extracted the core and ui zip files and they created their own **plugin** folder but when I run the eclipse and create a new Java Project and hit right click there is **no** **"Apache Derby" menu** shown while in the youtube tutorial there is. Also I found another [guide](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/Readme.html) but I am confused at STEP 1. Here are the files I downloaded (already extracted in eclipse directory).

[image]

Comment: Can't you simply install the plugin from the eclipse marketplace?

Comment: Support for the Derby plugins was dropped a long time ago. Since they use the old Eclipse 2.1 format they don't run on modern Eclipse releases.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645223/is-it-possible-to-use-derby-from-apache-in-eclipse-now-that-they-stopped-develop?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the info. Because I am trying to create a desktop application just a small one and plan to use an installer or just a runnable jar on different devices.