# Error adding Derby nature in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

Using:

1. java se 1.7 
   2.Eclipse kepler 
   3.Derby plugins: 
   derby_core_plugin 10.2.2.0
   derby_ui_plugin 1.0.0

Problem faced:
I installed these plugins and extracted in my plugins folder of the eclipse.Then I right clicked on my file and clicked on Apache Derby->"Add derby nature".It then shows the following error:

> Apache Derby Ui Plug-in Error adding Derby jars to the project:
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow cannot be cast to
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow

Any idea?
What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12645223/193453

Answer (score 0):

The Derby Eclipse plugins are extremely old and don't work with Eclipse 4.x versions of Eclipse.